# How to download the contents of website (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/) and all sub-directories

Tags: ubuntu, url, download, installation, wget

I want to download the contents (directory) and sub-directories from about URL. Is there a easy way to do this in Windows or Linux (command line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains archive.ubuntu.com \
     --no-parent \
         http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/
```

The options are:

--recursive: download the entire Web site.

--domains website.org: don't follow links outside ubuntu.com.

--no-parent: don't follow links outside the directory images.

--page-requisites: get all the elements that compose the page (images, CSS and so on).

--convert-links: convert links so that they work locally, off-line.

--restrict-file-names=windows: modify filenames so that they will work in Windows as well.

--no-clobber: don't overwrite any existing files (used in case the download is interrupted and resumed).